# SVG animation scrolling on single page website

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, parallax, scrollmagic

How can I achieve **SVG animation scrolling in a single page website.** I would like to make something like these websites https://onedesigncompany.com/approach and http://www.happyapps.io/. I like the first one more because the scrollup and scrolldown controls the animation.

I don't have any of my SVG code yet . trying to figure out how to get this pipeline workflow animation on scroll. I am using simple bootstrap starter template.

Need your suggestions

Thanks

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: ok, Thanks Robert for your suggestion to improve my question. I will try to edit my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try http://greensock.com/svg-tips

Greenstock is spezialized in animations, used for banners etc. Definityl a good resource for animations in general.

However animations are not easy and require a lot of work to get them right! Agreed to close this because the topic is way to large for an answer, it's more a study :D

Comment: Thanks stefan for the website. I found the one which I was looking for my project. It helped.